# Make \cref refer to Appendix instead of Chapter

Tags: appendices

I'm trying to make \cref refer to 'Appendix A' instead of 'Chapter A'.

I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}
```

In text, I use the following to make the Appendix:

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Categorization of compliance rules}
{\label{app:categorization}}
\end{appendices}
```

and the following to refer to it in text:

```
\cref{app:categorization}
```

To problem is that this gives me Chapter A, but I would like Appendix A. Which is weird because in the PDF it says that the Appendix chapter is called 'Appendix A'.

How can I make /cref say Appendix instead of Chapter?

Comment: Try to replace `\begin{appendices} \end{appendices}` by `\appendix`.

Comment: wow, that was obvious. Thanks!